# Windows 10 - MSTSC UI has very bad performance

Tags: windows-10, performance, remote-desktop, sql-server

About a month ago I reinstalled my PC at work and put Windows 10 on it after I received my new SSD. While the system itself runs very smooth, the MSTSC UI (the connection dialog) is pretty much unusable.

First thing is, it takes about one to two minutes to start up. Now, when I begin typing in the IP address, the application stops responding. About a few (10-20) seconds later, sometimes even a minute, it suddenly lets me click the "Connect" button. Upon clicking the UI stops responding again until it eventually connects to the server. When connected to the RDP server, everything works just fine.

I can't figure out what's wrong here. Almost everything else runs fine, except for the SQL Server Management Studio (doesn't matter which version). Perhaps it might be related. Issue is that upon hitting the connect button in SSMS, the connect dialog vanishes without anything else happening. It sure tries to connect because it notices when I type in a wrong password, so there is something fishy with some MS applications on my PC.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, this is going to drive me crazy.

Edit: I finally found a solution to both issues (MSTSC and SQL Server Management Studio).

This has to be added to the registry:
`[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\Protect\Providers\df9d8cd0-1501-11d1-8c7a-00c04fc297eb]
"ProtectionPolicy"=dword:00000001`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for my issue was to add the following to the registry:

`[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\Protect\Providers\df9d8cd0-1501-11d1-8c7a-00c04fc297eb]
"ProtectionPolicy"=dword:00000001`

Now MSTSC works just fine, as well as the SQL Server Management Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Try running [process monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) to see what it's doing in the background during the freezes.

Comment: I just took at look at what the process is doing. It's reading some values from the registry which all appears to be successful. Here's the log, I marked the point where it froze: https://pastebin.com/ntbaYiiu

So, I went on to check further and it turned out the main thread is suspended in the state Wait:WrLpcReply.

This is the stack of the thread:
`ntdll.dll!NtAlpcSendWaitReceivePort+0x14
RPCRT4.dll!I_RpcGetBufferWithObject+0x1e4f
RPCRT4.dll!NdrClientCall3+0x1e90
RPCRT4.dll!NdrClientCall3+0x10c
sechost.dll!CredReadW+0x78
mstsc.exe+0x86a98`

Comment: I think it's unlikely to be this, but could you please clear out the RDP Server History? It won't take long and rules that out. http://woshub.com/how-to-clear-rdp-connections-history/

Comment: Also try logging into the PC as a different user, does the problem still appear?

Comment: I finally found a solution to both issues (MSTSC and SQL Server Management Studio).

This has to be added to the registry:
`[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\Protect\Providers\df9d8cd0-1501-11d1-8c7a-00c04fc297eb]
"ProtectionPolicy"=dword:00000001`

Answer (score -1):

Please try to run mstsc.exe in Admin mode. (Go to the folder where it is installed, right click and Run as Administrator)
Also, try finding out if it is getting contention with other programs. Close everything and try running mstsc only and see if the same behavior persists.
This article might also be of help: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/6ed6500d-33f7-4f0c-89fb-8d8442c7a229/extremely-slow-rdp-session-solved?forum=winserverTS

Comment: I already tried doing so. Starting it as administrator doesnt change anything. Also, the article you've linked to refers to an established connection that doesn't work properly whereas I am experiencing issues _before_ even connecting anywhere. Closing all other applications didn't yield better results as well.

Some information on the system (although I'm more than sure it should be enough..):
CPU: Intel i7 2600
RAM: 16GB
OS: Windows 10 Pro x64
SSD: Samsung 850 EVO (250GB)